# svn2git gives Checksum Mismatch

Tags: git, svn, svn2git

I'm converting a bunch of SVN projects to Git, and svn2git has been working great for about 50 projects so far!

I got a Checksum Mismatch error on a decent sized SVN project with a good number of tags (~30).  Here's the message:

```
    r10249 = 6d53867481065872427e683dc70450d8c346224c (refs/remotes/svn/tags/5.1.0@14147-)
            M       release/00.xx/tools/oc4j-ant-deploy.xml
    r10553 = 89549f20466994266b4dafe374217759414c8606 (refs/remotes/svn/tags/5.1.0@14147-)
    Checksum mismatch: mortar/tags/00.xx/tools/oc4j-ant-deploy.xml e2fd9d6b9e69989d19b844002fb9f96a89616b36
    expected: b0efadeaa213072bbc65242dc13492ef
         got: abf410f39b8dcb75c8a654c305167bd7

    command failed:
    git svn fetch
```

Most of the googling and research I've done ends up talking about how to fix your current SVN project to gibe with the server.  When running svn2git, it should be just reading the svn repository.  This is probably a problem with the SVN project, but since it's reading it off of the server, I'm not sure what to do to resolve the problem.

Has anyone else encountered this while running svn2git?  How did you get around it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Run [`svnadmin verify`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svnadmin.c.verify.html) against the Subversion repository to check its consistency. There is a chance that the repository is corrupted.